# TypeInformation not defined

Tags: apache-flink

```scala
object EventConsumer {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env  = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val data1 =   env.readTextFile("file:////some_events.txt");
    // Define the data source
    data1 .map (new myMapFunction)
  }

  class myMapFunction extends MapFunction[String,Unit]
  {
    override def map(in: String): Unit = {
      println(in)
    }
  }
}
```

Really stuck with this compilation error for a long time, any help please.

```
Error:(27, 15) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[String]
      flatMap { _.split("\n")}.filter(_.nonEmpty).map (new myMapFunction)

Error:(24, 15) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$2: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[Unit], implicit evidence$3: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Unit])org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[Unit].
Unspecified value parameters evidence$2, evidence$3.
    data1.map (new myMapFunction)
              ^
              ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Flink's Scala DataSet API it is necessary to add the following import to your code: `import org.apache.flink.api.scala._`.

When using Flink's Scala DataStream API you have to import `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._`.

The reason is that the package object contains a function which generates the missing `TypeInformation` instances.